# Disable Delete List Permission in Sharepoint

Tags: list, permissions, sharepoint-list

Can I disable the delete list permission in SharePoint?

How can I customize the edit or contribute permission to remove the delete capability?

Thanks

Comment: which version of SharePoint you are using?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Prevent users from deleting any list in a site or just specific ones?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own Permission level in SharePoint according to your need.

Either you can create a new permission level from start or you can copy an existing permission level and make some changes like removing deletion capability.

Check below article:

[Create a Permission Level](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/how-to-create-and-edit-permission-levels#create-a-permission-level).

Answer (score 1):

Contribute permission is not having create list or delete list capabilities,
Edit permission is having both capabilities, to remove those permission use following steps.

Go to top level site settings -> Site Permissions
[image]

Click on permission level:
[image]

Uncheck Manage list option:
[image]
Above steps will disable create and delete functionality.

Comment: do you have a sample picture for this? As I cant find manage list. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated my answer with screenshots, please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you could also just reconfigure your list(s) to not allow deletion by anyone.

Using PnP PowerShell:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url <WebUrl>
$list = Get-PnPList <list name>
$list.AllowDeletion = $false
$list.Update()
Invoke-PnPQuery
```